# OpenGL deferred shading transparency

Tags: opengl, deferred-rendering

I'am trying to draw transparent textures in deferred shading.
This is gBuffer layout:

```
_depthComponentTexture = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_NEAREST);        
_worldNormalSpecPower = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
_albedoSpecularIntensity = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
_3unusedShaderless = new Texture(_width, _height, GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA, GL_NEAREST);
```

In forward rendering simply calling glEnabeld blend and blendFunc worked as expected, but since i switched to deferred it doesnt. Do i need to reserve alpha channel in albedo/diffuse part of the gbuffer? Also GL_ONE to GL_ONE works fine for light accumulation.

What i tried:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: There is no easy-straight forward way to include transparency in a deferred renderer. You might want to have a look at depth-peeling or order-independent transparency (OIT).

Comment: Simply put: 1. deferred shading 2. forward pass tranparent objects to another FBO with blending 3. blend 1 and 2 and discard fragments that are further away from deferred shaders depth?

Comment: You can also add all transparent object in a forward-rendering pass to the deferred result. This way you don't have to do the final merge and transparent objects behind solid ones are discarded immediately. From your question I thought you are looking for a way to render transparency object without forward rendering.

Comment: Do you mean add transparent objects on top of albedo of gBuffer? That is what i tried to do and it failed. Any examples of this? Thanks btw.

Comment: No. You do the complete deferred shading first (including illumination pass). Then you use the final color buffer and the depth buffer and render the transparent geometry on top of that.